# How can a libertarian oppose private property such as cookies?

Tags: libertarianism, property, intellectual-property

I have heard the argument that is made (usually) for a plot of land. We deprived someone of it, therefore it's wrong under libertarian principles. But what about newly generated property, like intellectual property, or, say, property generated with the fair exchange and agreement with other individuals. For example, if everyone is happy to give me flour and butter (for an agreed price or in exchange for something) and I make cookies, what's wrong with me owning those cookies?

Or maybe no libertarian would object to this?

Comment: Where did those people get the flour and butter from?

Comment: oh. maybe you are thinking of what's called libertarian now in america. I am talking about the 'original' libertarian point of view.

Comment: oerkelens. I see what you're getting at, but let's say the state provides a plot of land to each citizen (or a bit of money to each citizen) but then they make different use of it. Some throw a party on that land, some plant seeds to grow wheat, to make flour to make cookies. Is there something wrong (from the libertarian point of view) with this person owning those cookies?

Comment: If you are using a definition not in line with the tag you should include that definition.

Comment: erm, it is in line with the definition. but the 'current affairs' in the US have taken a turn where the libertarian idea of minimal state approaches a 'fight between all' meaning. That's not an obvious definition of 'libertarianism' and it's certainly not the SE definition. Understandably, SE definitions try to cover a broad group of cases, not just one embodiment. Otherwise the tag 'apple' should be used for, say, Granny Smith, whereas it's for all apples.

Comment: When you think that Libertarianism means one doesn't have right to private property or the value they create, then you either grossly misunderstood something or have a very weird definition of Libertarianism (it sounds more like Communism to me). Note that [there is not just one single definition of Libertarianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libertarianism#Prominent_currents). Could you post a reference to the definition of Libertarianism on which your question is based?

Comment: If you think a tag ought to be changed you can bring it up in meta (once you have 5 rep), but the existing questions use it in the American sense. If you clarify whose thinking you are interested in we might be able to answer.

Comment: see [this question about libertarian intellectual property](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/352/can-copyright-be-interpreted-as-a-liberal-economic-policy?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Perhaps OP sees broad generalizations about ***liberalism*** and is confusing that with libertarianism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Libertarian would object because it takes labor, or effort to make a cookie, and **your labor is your own**.

A cookie is more than just raw material.  So long as the materials were obtained fairly.  If you obtain something fairly, you own it and can do with it what you will.  When you add your effort and cookies are the result, you own the cookies and can do with them as you wish, no one else has any claim at all on your cookies.  *Your effort is your own*.  what your effort is worth is dependent upon what others would be willing to exchange for your cookies.

What you charge for your cookies is going to be the cost of materials plus what you feel is the cost of your effort to make the cookies.  If the market decides that is fair, great. If not, you keep the cookies.

In general, a Libertarian is fine with pretty much anything so long as a fair exchange is decided upon between individuals, and that my exercise of rights does not impinge upon yours.  Government, if any, need s to keep the heck out of everyone's way as much as possible.

Libertarians, for the most part, will acknowledge that a functioning Anarchy is impossible for anything but a small community.  Government needs to exist as a framework, but needs to be very strictly limited.  You know like making sure the government allows for freedom of religion, or speech, or association, or maybe limiting the governments ability to take property without due process or to posses arms to use against a tyrannical government....

Comment: *Government, if any, need s to keep the heck out of everyone's way as much as possible.* this is an over simplification I think.  It would be better said governement is there to handle exceptional cases, provide a system for civil resolution of disputes, and to protect the rights when they are infringed by others.

Comment: Fairly stated, though yours is probably more precise.  To me "As much as possible" does include exceptional cases and civil resolution of disputes, etc.  The philosophy of it stands.  Government doesn't go where it's not absolutely needed.  It's the goal that may not ever be truly realized, but is something to work toward.